# Swift package manager - Has no manifest error

Tags: swift, git, vapor, swift-package-manager

I created a Swift Package Manager library, and deployed it on my GitLab with a tag number 0.1.0. I'm now trying to add this package to my new vapor project by adding:

```
.package(url: "http://mygit.git/", from: "0.1.0").
```

When I try to make a "vapor update" I get a backgroundExecute error saying that my SPM has no manifest for version 0.1.0…

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to reach your project by branch or commit instead of tag.

Comment: btw, does your library have `Package.swift`? wanna test you lib, if possible please find me in discord as `imike#3049`

Comment: Hi @imike I tried .package(url: "http://myPackage.git", .branch("dev")) without success and yes the lib contains a package.swift. I tried to send you a friend request in discord but can't work.. mine is Mickaël#0137

Comment: Thanks for reaching me on Discord. The problem was just in `Package.swift` which should be in the root directory.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing the same error.

Answer (score 14):

The `Package.swift` file has to be in the root directory.

Comment: It is for me, and I'm still getting this.

Answer (score 1):

For me I was trying to add the package by right-clicking on a project and instead had to go to File->Add Packages....  No idea why this is different but there you go.